# URL hack for Add Products button in Lightning

Tags: lightning, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, urlhacking

The following button code opens the Add Products screen in Classic:

```
/ui/opportunity/SelectSearch?relatedListId=PricebookEntry&addTo={!Opportunity.Id}
```

Is there a Lightning equivalent?

Bonus points for a parameter to sort products by Product Family.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be expected behavior in salesforce, when you click it opens add products screen in classic and switch backs to lightning once you click on save.

Below doesn't seem to work.

```
{!IF(
$User.UIThemeDisplayed =='Theme4d',
URLFOR('/lightning/o/opportunity/xxxxxx'),
URLFOR('/ui/opportunity/xxxxxx')
)}
```

Unfortunately, To handle this use case you need to create lightning component.